# Java, getting a null value after starting a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to run this code in my android application in a non GUI related class.

```
Thread connection = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        streamSource = new StreamSource(conn.getInputStream());
                        writer = new CharArrayWriter();
                        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);
                        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
                        transformer.transform(streamSource, streamResult);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
              });
        connection.start();
```

The issue is that when I call *writer*, I am getting a null value.
Writer is defined as a static global variable as well as streamSource.
I'm not good with threads and this seems like my main thread is not seeing that my writer is created.

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that the started thread have had time to initialize `writer` before you read it?

Comment: how do i make sure? should i wait before starting my thread?

Comment: Have you tried Class.writer = new CharArrayWriter() ?

Comment: So you defined writer as a static global and trying to initialize it within the thread? Bad idea. Define in within the thread. Or define it once if you want to share and sure that object is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable *Writer* is in another class (thread) therefor you do not have access to it.
It is static, that's the cause of being able to access it theoretically, But it is not initialized to the other thread.

Please create the variable where you need it - or "outsource" the complete action taking place there.

**EDIT** : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
Here is some information about Threads and processes in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Start your thread after you have initilized the writer object. If you need both threads runing at the same time, then the easy way is to run a while loop checking if `writer != null` with `Thread.sleep` on every iteration